# File/Image stored to s3 bucket throws error 403 forbidden after 10-20 min when fetching the image again

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am developing react frontend with amplify backend. In the frontend i am uploading an avatar image to s3 bucket using Storage.put and storing the signed url to the "user" object. The amplify storage  is set up with read/write/delete for the owner and read permissions for guest users. The files are uploaded successfully into s3-bucket under public folder.

Now the weird thing. Everything works for the first 10-20 minutes. Then suddenly it throws 403 forbidden when accessing the image in my frontend.

Any ideas how to fix this?

I tried updating the bucket policy with following setup:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Frontend code for uploading image to s3:

```
  async function uploadImage(
    uri?: File,
    filename?: string
  ): Promise<string | null> {
    if (uri === null || !filename) return null;

    try {
      const result = await Storage.put(filename, uri, {
        level: "public",
        contentType: "image/*",
      });
      console.log("STORAGE PUT SUCCESS: ", result.key);
      const signedURL = await Storage.get(result.key); // get key from Storage.list
      console.log("STORAGE GET SUCCESS: ", signedURL);
      return signedURL;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("STORAGE PUT ERROR: ", err);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: The signed url expires after a few minutes. And / or the credentials used to sign the url expired.

Comment: so this means saving the signedURL to the user object is wrong? But how is the right approach? Always downloading the image to frontend??

Comment: Yes, you cannot save a presigned URL for long-term use. You have multiple options, your backend can always issue new presigned urls when the frontend asks for one, your S3 bucket could allow anonymous / public reads, you can have a cloudfront that allows anonymous requests and forwards them to S3, you could authenticate your frontend e.g. via cognito and grant read-only access to those credentials, etc.

Comment: Forgot to mention that. My frontend uses cognito for authentication, so the user already fetches as authenticated user.

Comment: If you grant the coginto role the right permissions the frontend should then be allowed to request the image directly instead of using a presigned url.

Comment: @luk2302 but then i would need to fetch it in a different way, right? It wouldn`t work with await Storage.get as this only gives me the signedURL. My "workaround" now is whenever the image gives me 403 i just fetch Storage.get and set the signed url for the image component directly. So the user avatar has actually not the image, additionally it has the image key. Not the best way but it works ...